# Making Y plane follow direction of building

Tags: coordinates, cesium

Here is my current code:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var redPlane = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red plane with black outline',
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-107.0, 40.0, 300000.0),
    plane : {
        plane : new Cesium.Plane(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Y, 0.0),
        dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian2(400000.0, 300000.0),     
        material : Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline : true,
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK

    }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

[image]